# Подсчет количества констант в enum. Где ошибка?

Tags: java

Дано скрытое перечисление с некоторыми константами в верхнем регистре.

Напишите программу, которая подсчитывает, сколько констант в перечислении начинается сo  «STAR».

```java
public class TheSecretEnumeration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Secret secret : Secret.values()) {
            if (secret.startsWith("STAR")) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Secret {
    STAR, CRASH, START;
    String str;

    Secret(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    Secret() {
    }

    public boolean startsWith(String star) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

В задаче дан шаблон:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}

/* At least two constants start with STAR
enum Secret {
    STAR, CRASH, START, // ...
}
*/
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос - где ошибка и что не работает?

Comment: Compilation error
Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            if (secret.startsWith("STAR")) {
                      ^
  symbol:   method startsWith(String)
  location: variable secret of type Secret
1 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int count = 0;
    for (Secret secret : Secret.values()) {
        if (secret.name().startsWith("STAR")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()

Comment: Failed. Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong.

Comment: @Poul What "Failed"? Who "Cannot check answer"? Which "output format"?

Comment: https://hyperskill.org/learn/daily/2970

Comment: @Poul может потому что count нужно выводить один раз после цикла, а не в нём делать вывод на каждое совпадение?

Comment: @Poul Это мне зачем ссылка? Человеческим языком Вы не можете объяснить?

Comment: @Igor code editor выдавал ошибку, из-за sout в цикле. Вынес за цикл - заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: @Poul Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

*Пока писал ответ, увидел, что @Igor уже обновил свой ответ.*

Добавлю, что можно так же через

```
secret.toString().startsWith("STAR");
```

но это не есть лучшая практика, т.к. метод `toString()` может быть переопределен для значений `Enum`, и его результат к тому моменту уже может не соответствовать ожиданиям.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
        for (Secret secret : Secret.values()) {
            if (secret.toString ().startsWith("STAR")) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}

enum Secret {
    STAR, CRASH, START, // ...
}
```

Из-за чего появляется ошибка

> Compilation error Main.java:18: error: duplicate class: Secret enum Secret {

Comment: А из-за чего она появляется?

Comment: Мне кажется, это новый вопрос и его нужно задать отдельно, дав ссылку на этот топик.